# Adding a line of text between each line of existing text R

Tags: r, text, edit

So I have a one-column data frame that contains serial numbers. Ex:

```
15161718191a
17272892020c
37464748494f
16263738393g
17738393303a
83849404040d
```

An I would like to add a "counter line" identifier between each serial code so it looks something like this:

```
Code1
15161718191a
Code2
17272892020c
Code3
37464748494f
Code4
16263738393g
Code5
17738393303a
Code6
83849404040d
```

As you can see, the word "Code" remains the same, but the numbers following it are iterative (Code1, Code2, etc). Is there a way to do this in an automated way for data sets that contain thousands of serial codes?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't really want to add those new lines _between_ the existing rows, do you? Surely you mean you want to create a second variable?

Comment: No, I need them in between the lines. The structure is crucial for a UNIX code I am running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way I can think of. Create a new data frame.

```
df = data.frame( col=c("15161718191a",
                 "17272892020c",
                 "37464748494f",
                 "16263738393g",
                 "17738393303a",
                 "83849404040d"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

n = nrow(df)
df2 = data.frame(col=rep(NA,2*n))
df2[1:n*2-1,] = df
df2[1:n*2,] = paste0( "Code", 1:n )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat convoluted way of doing it:

```
# Create some data
df<-data.frame(col=sample(LETTERS,100,replace=TRUE))
# Convert to a matrix, then convert to a vector.
df2<-data.frame(col=c(t(data.frame(paste0('Code',seq_along(df$col)),df$col))))
#     col
# 1 Code1
# 2     P
# 3 Code2
# 4     H
# 5 Code3
# 6     P
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, just for fun:

```
d <- read.table(text='15161718191a
17272892020c
37464748494f
16263738393g
17738393303a
83849404040d', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data.frame(mycol=as.vector(rbind(paste0('Code', 1:nrow(d)), d[,1])))
#           mycol
# 1         Code1
# 2  15161718191a
# 3         Code2
# 4  17272892020c
# 5         Code3
# 6  37464748494f
# 7         Code4
# 8  16263738393g
# 9         Code5
# 10 17738393303a
# 11        Code6
# 12 83849404040d
```

Comment: Thanks! That is much simpler.